# Ambiguous modifications to a view that has a subquery in the FROM clause?

Tags: mysql, sql

> The `SELECT` statement cannot contain a subquery in the `FROM` clause.

If you modify a view that contains such a subquery, why is the modifcation of the base relation on which it depends ambiguous?

**EDIT**: I've come closer to finding a solution. If you have a table that contains, student ID's and names, and you want to create a view that contains all non-unique names, as in:

```
create view NonUnique as
select * from Student S1
where exists (select * from Student S2
              where S1.sID <> S2.sID
              and S2.name = S1.name)
```

then `delete from NonUnique` is specifying an ambiguous modifcation to the `Student` table, because you could clear out the view by deleting all students, or just a handful of students such  that only uniquely named students remain.

**Are there any other examples of ambiguous modifications we could make to a view that contains a subquery?**

Answer (score 6):

I don't see any ambiguity in the delete. `DELETE FROM aView ;` should delete (if allowed) all rows in the underlying table that are in the View.

```
CREATE TABLE Student
  ( sid INT NOT NULL
  , name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
  , PRIMARY KEY (sid)
  ) ;

INSERT INTO Student
  (sid, name)
VALUES
  (1, 'Alex'),
  (2, 'Bill'),
  (3, 'Cate'),
  (4, 'Dean'),
  (5, 'Eve'),
  (6, 'Alex'),
  (7, 'Bill'),
  (8, 'Cate') ;

CREATE VIEW NonUnique AS
SELECT * 
FROM Student S1
WHERE EXISTS 
      ( SELECT * 
        FROM Student S2
        WHERE S1.sID <> S2.sID
          AND  S2.name = S1.name
      ) ;

DELETE FROM NonUnique ;
```

It works fine in SQL products that have implemented `DELETE` correctly. See the SQL-Fiddles for [SQL-Server](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c75a2/1) and [Oracle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8f7d5/1):

```
SELECT * FROM Student ;
```

Result:

```
sid | name
----------
  4 | Dean
  5 | Eve
```

---

MySQL provides error: `The target table NonUnique of the DELETE is not updatable`

Postgres gives: `ERROR: cannot delete from view "nonunique":`

---

If you try this in MySQL:

```
DELETE s 
FROM Student AS s
   JOIN 
     NonUnique AS n 
       ON n.sid = s.sid ;
```

or this:

```
DELETE
FROM Student 
WHERE EXISTS
      ( SELECT *
        FROM NonUnique 
        WHERE NonUnique.sid = Student.sid 
      ) ;
```

the error is: `The definition of table 'NonUnique' prevents operation DELETE on table 'Student'.`

---

In Postgres however, the second statement succeeds and deletes the correct rows.

[MySQL](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c2f78) succeeds only if you manage to hide the view inside a derived table:

```
DELETE s 
FROM Student AS s
   JOIN 
     ( SELECT *
       FROM NonUnique
     ) AS n 
     ON n.sid = s.sid ;
```

Comment: Thanks! It's clear that different DBMS implementations have different modification permissions, but wouldn't the delete I cited be ambiguous? Say we have table T that contains 1, 2, and 2. And we create a NonUnique View. This view contains the tuples 1, 2. If we delete all from the view, we have two options: delete all tuples from the base table or leave one 2. In either case, the view will still be empty.

Comment: It's different to "DELETE all FROM aVIEW" that what you describe. I would call it: "DELETE **(one-by-one)** until the VIEW is empty". But operations in SQL are done in sets, not one by one. Either the whole set or nothing at all.

Comment: If DELETEs were done that way, one by one, it would be ambiguous then. You are right in that.

Comment: And since you are using MySQL, it is doing it wrong and (sometimes). UPDATEs and DELETEs in MySQL are done one by one.

Comment: If the modification is DELETE * from aforementioned-view, then is this modification ambiguous?

Comment: I did not understand your last comment.

Comment: The ambiguity I'm referring to is: will all tuples be removed from the base relation or only the set of tuples that will render an empty view?

Comment: The correct non-ambiguous behaviour is all rows that have duplicate names (and are seen in the View just before the DELETE), all these rows to be deleted.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15095/discussion-between-ypercube-and-rose-perrone)

Answer (score 0):

My instructor wrote this answer:

The SQL standard does not allow that view to be modified, because of the ambiguity.

@ypercube makes the point that there does exist a well-defined way to translate modifications to that view to modifications to the base table. However, there are other modifications to the base table that could similarly modify the view. Thus, I think "delete * from the-specificied-view" is actually ambiguous.